# Redis-Sentinel with Redis whose CONFIG command is renamed

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

The `CONFIG` command is renamed to `CONFIG_2267bccb973c432d96a26e96ca50860a`

As I know, Redis-sentinel relies on this command, yes?  How can configure redis-sentinel to use the renamed command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Redis sentinel doesn't support renamed config commands. By the way this is an admin question so it belongs on serverfault.